# How to download a file from a link that is a forced download

Tags: r, httr

Using R, I want to grab the .csv from this site: https://vacationwithoutacar.com/gvrat-tracking/ but there is no link associated with the download it just pops up automatically. Usually, I would use `httr` to download but when I right-click the the link it doesn't give me the option to copy a URL. There's not much of a reproducible example because, well, I can't even get the file downloaded.

```
GET("https://vacationwithoutacar.com/gvrat-tracking/",
    write_disk("gvrat.txt", 
               overwrite = TRUE)
    )
```

Comment: it's a blob url, `blob:https://vacationwithoutacar.com/3bd97909-dd8f-4903-892d-e56765ea4527`. Please see if it helps.

Comment: @RiteshPorwal - it now says the file has been removed or deleted. How did you find that link?

Comment: I searched about blob objects and i found that they are stored locally in the browser not on the server. So u can't access a blob url by just like a normal url. So maybe the url i gave is not working for everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work...

I opened the URL in chrome, hit F12, clicked network, trash can to clear, reload page. Then looked for some request to download the data. I saw the URL below returned JSON.

```
library(jsonlite)
df <- fromJSON("https://vacationwithoutacar.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=wp_ajax_ninja_tables_public_action&table_id=2596&target_action=get-all-data&default_sorting=old_first")
> head(df)
pos   bib participantsname event  home g   a miles    km yourapproximatelocation   comp projfin 51 52 53 54
1   1 17395  Gingerbread Man GVRAT US-TN M 145 275.6 443.5           Cowley Hollow 43.50%     tbd 83 43 49 52
2   2  1074    Terri Biloski GVRAT CA-ON F  44 274.6 442.0           Cowley Hollow 43.30%     tbd 63 59 52 52
3   3  1429     Dave Proctor GVRAT CA-AB M  39 255.3 410.8           Cowley Hollow 40.30%     tbd 62 62  5 62
4   4   743       John Sharp GVRAT US-TX M  42 235.0 378.2             Reed Hollow 37.10%     tbd 34 41 46 54
5   5   386       Roc Powell GVRAT US-OH M  60 226.0 363.7          Britton Hollow 35.60%     tbd 35 75 63 43
6   6   322  Rob Donkersloot GVRAT    AU M  60 190.7 306.9          past Deerfield 30.10%     tbd 42 42 43 32
  55 56 57 58 59 51_1
1 48                 
2 48                 
3 63                 
4 60                 
5 10                 
6 32
```